# Python Generator Cutoff

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

I have a generator that will keep giving numbers that follow a specific formula. For sake of argument let's say this is the function:

```
# this is not the actual generator, just an example
def Generate():
    i = 0
    while 1:
        yield i
        i+=1
```

I then want to get a list of numbers from that generator that are below a certain threshold. I'm trying to figure out a pythonic way of doing this. I don't want to edit the function definition. I realize you could just use a while loop with your cutoff as the condition, but I'm wondering if there is a better way. I gave this a try, but soon realized why it wouldn't work.

```
l = [x for x in Generate() x<10000] # will go on infinitely
```

So is there a correct way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) solution to create another iterator:

```
from itertools import takewhile
l = takewhile(lambda x: x < 10000, generate())
```

Wrap it in `list()` if you are sure you want a list:

```
l = list(takewhile(lambda x: x < 10000, generate()))
```

Or if you want a list and like inventing wheels:

```
l = []
for x in generate():
    if x < 10000:
        l.append(x)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Worth noting that `itertools.takewhile` will stop when an item fails the predicate. The usefulness of `takewhile` depends on the OP's execution requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your generator within another generator:

```
def no_more_than(limit):
    def limiter(gen):
        for item in gen:
            if item > limit:
                break
            yield item
    return limiter

def fib():
    a,b = 1,1
    while 1:
        yield a
        a,b = b,a+b


cutoff_at_100 = no_more_than(100)
print list(cutoff_at_100(fib()))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.takewhile` will only work until it comes across an item that does not fulfill the predicate. If you need to return all values from a possibly unordered iterable, I'd recommend using `itertools.ifilter` for Python 2.x as in

```
from itertools import ifilter
f = ifilter(lambda x: x < 400, gen())
f.next()
```

This filtered a generator yielding random integers between 0 and 400 as hoped.

FWIW `itertools.ifilter` was deprecated in Python 3.x in favour of the built-in `filter()` which has slightly different syntax for iterating

```
f = filter(lambda x: x < 400, gen())
next(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it on a zip generator of a range of the limit:

```
gen = range(100_000_000_000)
limit = 10
(z[1] for z in zip(range(limit), gen))
```

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) creates a tuple, that is the reason for `z[1]`

This may be used on `for` loops:

```
for g in (z[1] for z in zip(range(limit), gen)):
    print(g)
```

Or you could use [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
wrap = lambda gen, limit: (z[1] for z in zip(range(limit), gen))
for g in wrap(gen, 10):
    print(g)
```

Comment: This solution does not terminate for me. The 10 numbers are issued, but it does not stop afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @fcdt I fixed using zip, that also uses a generator. This [post](https://treyhunner.com/2018/02/python-range-is-not-an-iterator/) helped me to understand

Answer (score -1):

Just use a counter for an infinite generator:

```
gen=Generate()        # your generator function example
l=[gen.next() for i in range(100)]
```

But since it is a generator, use a generator expression:

```
seq=(gen.next() for i in xrange(100))  #need x in xrange in Python 2.x; 3.x use range
```

---

**Edit**

OK, then just use a controller:

```
def controler(gen,limit):
    n=gen.next()
    while n<limit:
        yield n
        n=gen.next()

seq=[i for i in controler(Generate(),100)]
```

Comment: I wasn't looking for a solution to give me x number of elements, I want to get all elements under x. This solution will give me the first 100 elements, which for the example I gave will all be all the numbers under 100, but the point is I don't know how many will be generated.

Answer (score -1):

replace `Generate()` with `xrange(10000)`